# T-SQL equivalent of Oracle's collection methods (first, last, next)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

We're moving from Oracle to SQL Server and I'm converting a query from a table variable populated with a BULK COLLECT INTO query.  I'm thinking of using a cursor (definitely open to other suggestions), but in the Oracle code that processes the query it's using `Table_var.FIRST` `.NEXT` and `.LAST`.  Here's some sample code of how it's using these.  It appears that the first/next/last are giving indexes into the table var's records.

```
TYPE Pers_DOB_LastInitial IS RECORD (
  Person_ID Person.Person_ID%TYPE,
  DOB Person.Birthdate%TYPE,
  LastInitial VARCHAR2(1)
);

TYPE Dup_Table IS TABLE OF Pers_DOB_LastInitial INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

Dup_Tab Dup_Table;
```

and a function that uses these types:

```
FUNCTION Last_In_Group( pStart NUMBER, pDOB Person.Birthdate%TYPE, pLastInitial VARCHAR2 )
     RETURN NUMBER IS
  vResult NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF pStart = Dup_Tab.LAST THEN
     RETURN pStart;
  END IF;

  vResult := pStart;

  FOR vIndex IN pStart .. Dup_Tab.LAST LOOP
     IF Dup_Tab.EXISTS( vIndex ) THEN
        IF Dup_Tab( vIndex ).DOB = pDOB AND Dup_Tab( vIndex ).LastInitial = pLastInitial THEN
           vResult := vIndex;
        ELSE
           EXIT;
        END IF;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN vResult;
END Last_In_Group;
```

I don't need the coding done for me, just need to be pointed in the right direction.  I'm thinking of using a cursor, but the only thing I'm familiar with is simply fetching the next record from a cursor in T-SQL and want to see if there are equivalent ways to reference row indexes for cursors (or temp tables).

---

**EDIT**: I've just discovered the following and am looking into it.  Definitely open to hints on whether this is a good path to pursue or if cursors are still better.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/operations-no-cursors/2/

```
DECLARE @dupTab TABLE (
    person_id numeric(8,0),
    DOB date,
    LastInitial char(1)
)

INSERT @dupTab
SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but have you looked at the new [LEAD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx), [LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), [FIRST_VALUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx), and [LAST_VALUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) keywords in Sql Server 2012?

Comment: No, that is something completely different.

Comment: I've update the question to (hopefully) make it a bit more clear what I'm asking and provide better sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called Dup_Tab, and @DOB and @LastInitial are variables you passed into your function, might this work?

```
select PersonID from(
select
 rank = row_number() over (order by DOB DESC, LastInitial DESC),
 PersonID
from dup_tab where DOB=@DOB and LastInitial=@LastInitial
) subgroup 
where rank=1
```

It's just using the windowed Rank() function to assign each record a row number based on DOB/LastInitial ordered last-first and then you select the row with rank = 1, giving you the last record in the set of persons with a specific DOB and LastInitial.

Answer (score 0):

I translated your sample code into it's SQL-Server counterpart. If you want to do row-by-row processing the best performing way is imo to use a FAST_FORWARD cursor.

code:

```
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Last_In_Group]') AND xtype in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
        drop function  Last_In_Group
    go

    create function Last_In_Group(@pStart  int, @pDOB date, @pLastInitial varchar(1))
    returns int
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Dup_Tab TABLE(
            Person_ID int,
            DOB date,
            LastInitial varchar(1)
        )
        -- populate the table with some data
        insert @Dup_Tab values
        (1, '31.12.2013', 'P'), (2, '24.12.2013', 'C'), (3, '24.12.2013', 'C')

        declare @vResult int = 0,
                @cDOB date,
                @cLastInitial varchar(1)

        if(@vResult = @pStart) return @pStart
        set @vResult = @pStart

        -- loop over your data with a fast cursor
        declare cur cursor FAST_FORWARD for select DOB, LastInitial from @Dup_Tab
        open cur
        fetch next from cur
        into @cDOB, @cLastInitial

        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            if(@cDOB = @pDOB and @cLastInitial = @pLastInitial)
                set @vResult += 1
            fetch next from cur
            into @cDOB, @cLastInitial
        end

        return @vResult;
    end
    go

    print dbo.Last_In_Group(1, '24.12.2013', 'C')
    go
```

It might not work as your sample above but I hope this gives you some hint where to go further.